# Find consecutive datetime from array php

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for my English ,I am new here and new to PHP.I have array like below,I was trying find count of consecutive date-time from for every user within 10 min,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => A
            [time] => 2018-08-01 14:12:00

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => B
            [time] => 2018-08-01 14:12:00

        )
    [2] => Array
        (

            [user] => A
            [time] => 2018-08-01 14:13:00

        )
    [3] => Array
        (

            [user] => A
            [time] => 2018-08-01 14:14:00

        )
    [4] => Array
        (

            [user] => A
            [time] => 2018-08-01 14:15:00

        )
    [5] => Array
        (

            [user] => B
            [time] => 2018-08-01 14:50:00

        )
)
```

I was trying to find consecutive datetime count of user click within 10 min,Like user A click 4 times consecutively within 10 min and User B click only 1 time within 10 min

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => A
            [count] => 4

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => B
            [count] => 1

        )
)
```

Comment: do you have this data in MySQL? If yes, you can do that in MySQL itself. If not, that do two loops to get that data.

Comment: Also you're talking about any 10  min range or last 10 minutes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function with your array and the `$user` you want to count as parameter, and then loop into the array and sum +1 for each interaction that matches your prerequisites.

Assuming your parent array is named `$users`, you can do the following:

```
function countConsecutive($users, $username)
{
    $total = 0;

    foreach($users as $user) {
        if($user['user'] === $username && $user['time'] >= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-10 minutes'))) {
            $total++;
        }
    }

    return $total;
}
```

The return of the function will be the count of consecutive date-time from the user in the last 10 minutes.